# Common substring of two string in SQL

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql

I need to find common substring (without space) of two strings in SQL.

Query:

```
select *
from tbl as a, tbl as b
where a.str <> b.str
```

Sample data:

```
str1      | str2      | max substring without spaces
----------+-----------+-----------------------------
aabcdfbas | rikcdfva  | cdf
aaab akuc | aaabir a  | aaab
ab akuc   | ab atr    | ab
```

Comment: Wrong tool to be using for this problem.  You can do this in SQL Server as a stored procedure.  That would most be an exercise in writing stored procedure code to do things that aren't best done in a database.

Comment: In the stored proc, you might need to go through each character in the loop,

Comment: As already mentioned, SQL isn't optimal for this task. There's a nice article about it with a proposed solution. It should at the minimum be a good starting point. https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/blogs/string-comparisons-in-sql-the-longest-common-substring/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no question.

Comment: @HABO The OP is looking for the longest common substring (that does not contain spaces) between two strings in a table. Phil Factor's brilliant solution uses a Multi-Statement Table-Valued Function which is slower and can't be parallelized. It also does not account for ties.

Comment: @AlanBurstein Neither the title nor first (and only) sentence mention _longest_. Perhaps you're assuming that based on the sample data having a column header with "max" in it, though that might refer to ordering of results, e.g. "whiskey" and "frisky" both contain "isk" and "y", but the "y" is the maximum alphabetically. Although "I need" is prominent, I still see no question and no evidence of research.

Answer (score 8):

I disagree with those who say that SQL is not the tool for this job. Until someone can show me a faster way than my solution in ANY programming language, I will aver that SQL (written in a set-based, side-effect free, using only immutable variables) is the ***ONLY*** tool for this job (when dealing with varchar(8000)- or nvarchar(4000)). The solution below is for varchar(8000).

**1. A correctly indexed tally (numbers) table.**

```
-- (1) build and populate a persisted (numbers) tally 
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.tally') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.tally;
CREATE TABLE dbo.tally (n int not null);

WITH DummyRows(V) AS(SELECT 1 FROM (VALUES (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) t(N))
INSERT dbo.tally
SELECT TOP (8000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
FROM DummyRows a CROSS JOIN DummyRows b CROSS JOIN DummyRows c CROSS JOIN DummyRows d;

-- (2) Add Required constraints (and indexes) for performance
ALTER TABLE dbo.tally 
ADD CONSTRAINT pk_tally PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED(N) WITH FILLFACTOR = 100;

ALTER TABLE dbo.tally 
ADD CONSTRAINT uq_tally UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED(N);
```

*Note that a tally table function will not perform as well.*

**2. Using our tally table to return all possible substrings a string**

Using "abcd" as an example, let's get all of it's substrings. Note my comments.

```
DECLARE @s1 varchar(8000) = 'abcd';

SELECT
  position  = t.N,
  tokenSize = x.N,
  string    = substring(@s1, t.N, x.N)  
FROM       dbo.tally t -- token position
CROSS JOIN dbo.tally x -- token length
WHERE t.N <=  len(@s1) -- all positions
AND   x.N <=  len(@s1) -- all lengths
AND   len(@s1) - t.N - (x.N-1) >= 0 -- filter unessesary rows [e.g.substring('abcd',3,2)]
```

This returns

```
position    tokenSize   string
----------- ----------- -------
1           1           a
2           1           b
3           1           c
4           1           d
1           2           ab
2           2           bc
3           2           cd
1           3           abc
2           3           bcd
1           4           abcd
```

**3. dbo.getshortstring8K**

What's this function about? The first major optimization. We're going to break the shorter of the two strings into every possible substring then see if it exists in the longer string. If you have two strings (S1 and S2) and S1 is longer than S2, we know that none of the substrings of S1, that are longer than S2, will be a substring of S2. That's the purpose of dbo.getshortstring: to ensure that we don't perform any unnecessary substring comparisons. This will make more sense in a moment.

This is hugely important because, the number of substrings in a string can be calculated using a [Triangle Number Function](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/triangular-numbers.html). With **N** as the length (number of characters) in a string, the number of substrings can be calculated as **N*(N+1)/2**. E.g. "abc" has 6 substrings: 3*(3+1)/2 = 6; a,b,c,ab,bc,abc. If we're comparing "abc" to "abcdefgh" we don't need to check if "abcd" is a substring of "abc".

Breaking "abcdefgh" (length=8) into all possible substrings requires 8*(8+1)/2 = *36* operations (vs *6* for "abc").

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.getshortstring8k') IS NOT NULL DROP FUNCTION dbo.getshortstring8k;
GO
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.getshortstring8k(@s1 varchar(8000), @s2 varchar(8000))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS RETURN 
SELECT s1 = CASE WHEN LEN(@s1) < LEN(@s2) THEN @s1 ELSE @s2 END,
       s2 = CASE WHEN LEN(@s1) < LEN(@s2) THEN @s2 ELSE @s1 END;
```

**4. Finding all subsrings of the shorter string that exist in the longer string:**

```
DECLARE @s1 varchar(8000) = 'bcdabc', @s2 varchar(8000) = 'abcd';

SELECT
  s.s1, -- test to make sure s.s1 is the shorter of the two strings
  position  = t.N,
  tokenSize = x.N,
  string    = substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N)
FROM dbo.getshortstring8k(@s1, @s2) s --<< get the shorter string
CROSS JOIN dbo.tally t  
CROSS JOIN dbo.tally x
WHERE t.N between 1 and len(s.s1)
AND   x.N between 1 and len(s.s1)
AND   len(s.s1) - t.N - (x.N-1) >= 0
AND   charindex(substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N), s.s2) > 0;
```

**5. Retrieving ONLY the longest common substring(s)**

This is the easy part. We simply Add `TOP (1) WITH TIES` to our `SELECT` statement and we're all set. Here, the longest common substring is "bc" and "xx"

```
DECLARE @s1 varchar(8000) = 'xxabcxx', @s2 varchar(8000) = 'bcdxx';

SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
  position  = t.N,
  tokenSize = x.N,
  string    = substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N)
FROM dbo.getshortstring8k(@s1, @s2) s
CROSS JOIN dbo.tally t  
CROSS JOIN dbo.tally x
WHERE t.N between 1 and len(s.s1)
AND   x.N between 1 and len(s.s1)
AND   len(s.s1) - t.N - (x.N-1) >= 0
AND   charindex(substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N), s.s2) > 0
ORDER BY x.N DESC;
```

**6. Applying this logic to your table**

Using APPLY we replace my variables @s1 and @s2 with the t.str1 & t.str2. I add a filter to exclude matches that contain spaces (see my comments)... And we're off:

```
-- easily consumbable sample data
DECLARE @yourtable TABLE (str1 varchar(8000), str2 varchar(8000));
INSERT @yourtable 
VALUES ('aabcdfbas','rikcdfva'),('aaab akuc','aaabir a'),('ab akuc','ab atr');

SELECT str1, str2,  [max substring without spaces] = string
FROM @yourtable t
CROSS APPLY 
(
    SELECT TOP (1) WITH TIES 
      position  = t.N,
      tokenSize = x.N,
      string    = substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N)
    FROM dbo.getshortstring8k(t.str1, t.str2) s -- @s1 & @s2 replaced with str1 & str2 
    CROSS JOIN dbo.tally t  
    CROSS JOIN dbo.tally x
    WHERE t.N between 1 and len(s.s1)
    AND   x.N between 1 and len(s.s1)
    AND   len(s.s1) - t.N - (x.N-1) >= 0
    AND   charindex(substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N), s.s2) > 0
    AND   charindex(' ',substring(s.s1, t.N, x.N)) = 0 -- exclude substrings with spaces
    ORDER BY x.N DESC
) lcss;
```

**Results:**

```
str1        str2      max substring without spaces
----------- --------- ------------------------------
aabcdfbas   rikcdfva  cdf
aaab akuc   aaabir a  aaab
ab akuc     ab atr    ab
```

And the execution plan:

[image]

... No sorts or unnecessary operations. Just speed. For longer strings (e.g. 50 characters+) I have an even faster technique you can read about [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131759/is-there-a-sql-server-implementation-of-the-longest-common-substring-problem).

Comment: Would it not reduce most of the work to split into spaceless words first?

Comment: Perhaps, I didn't give it much thought. If you examine the first Nested Loops (inner join) in the execution plan - all the filtering is happening at once so I suspect it would not matter.

Comment: Possibly the most underrated answer in the history of stackoverflow. Have a updoote.

Comment: I just saw this. Thanks @Gustav