# Grouping Data and finding common string

Tags: python, sql, unix, sas, informatica

I have a generic requirement to group data and get the common string out of it. I am not sure which technology will work for this specific requirement . Hence mentioned it as generic. I currently have access to SQL,Unix commands, SAS , MSTR, Informatica, and Python.

**Actual Data:**

```
Field A| Field B | Field c
A      | 001     | Alan J
A      | 001     | Alan Walker 
A      | 001     | Walker Alan 
A      | 001     | Alexander AlanJoseph
```

**Required Output:**

```
Field A | Field B | Field C 
A       | 001     | Alan
```

**Note:** Based on grouping of Field A and Field B, need to find out the common pattern among the data in Field C

Could someone please help me out on this ?

Comment: This is not a suitable problem for SQL.  If you are looking for the longest common substring, then there might be appropriate libraries in an analytic tool/programming language such as SAS or Python.

Comment: This post may give you some direction- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49394121/common-substring-of-two-string-in-sql

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SAS. Your question can be done in many ways, I give you the DOW loop version.

```
data have;
    input A$ 1-3 B$ 12-15 C$ 21-43;
    cards;
    A      | 001     | Alan 
    A      | 001     | Alan Walker 
    A      | 001     | Walker Alan 
    A      | 001     | Alexander AlanJoseph
    B      | 002     | Jay 
    B      | 002     | Jay Zhou
    B      | 002     | JayJay 
;
run;

proc sort;
    by A B;
run;

data want(keep=A B C);
    length string $1024.;

    do until(last.B);
        set have;
        by A B;
        string = catx('@',string,C);
        count = sum(count,1);
    end;

    do until(last.B);
        set have;
        by A B;
        do i = 1 to count;
            if find(scan(string,i,'@'),cats(C)) then match = sum(match,1);
        end;
        if count = match then output;
    end;
run;

proc print;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have liked your approach. I have updated my input data set for the first record, in that case what modification is needed in the SAS code to fetch the result? The output has to display the common word for the group of field A and field B. Thanks

Comment: @Scott77 This is very diffcult to me, perhaps I can not help. Maybe you can google it for "longest common substring". I had did it but the anwser were all about 2 strings, not for n(n>2). I will take a good think the several days.

Answer (score 1):

Below is the solution,

**Sql**

```
select field_a, field_b, field_c from
(select distinct d1.*, row_number() over(partition by d1.field_a order by d1.field_c) 
as rnk from data d1
inner join data d2 on 
(instr(d1.field_c, d2.field_c) > 0)) where rnk=1;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=ccd9837b8e893ed42f8ade3b7e7e9d40

**Informatica**

Use Expression transformation, find the patter using `INSTR` function (you can also use regular expressions). Then the pass the ports to rank transformation and sort it be field_c and fetch top 1 values.

Comment: To understand the SQL : search each string in each other `((instr(d1.field_c, d2.field_c) > 0)` and then keep the one you find most times in other values `where rnk=1`